# vs c++ inline assembly __asm improper operand type when using 64 bit registers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I'm not sure why I can't store the 64 bit RAX register to a unit64_t data type.

Here is the code:

```
uint64_t    timerCounter = 0;

void volatile aTimer(void)
{
    //for (timerCounter = 0; ; timerCounter++);
    __asm
    {
        mov rax, 0
        nxtinc:
        inc rax
        mov timerCounter, rax // Improper Operand Type!!!
        jmp nxtinc
    }
```

}

Enviroment is VS2015 C++

Comment: When targeting 64-bit executables VC++ doesn't support inline assembly anymore. You can use compiler intrinsics that may provide some of the functionality you need or you'll have to create a separate assembly file with your function coded in assembly..

Comment: If this is a 32-bit MSVC/C++ project then you can't use 64-bit registers.